# CAS authentication with new spring boot application

Tags: spring, cas

I am working on a simple Spring boot web application, where I need to authenticate using the existing CAS Server. After successful authentication I need to capture user attributes, I followed the steps from the below URL and I configured cas and I am able to authenticate, but not able to get attributes. Did anyone accomplish this? if anyone has an idea how it works? Or someone can share the relevant information on this?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Put the relevant code base where you are stuck and what have you come up with so far, so that this community can take a look and help. Also which link you are referring to?

Comment: @Bean
 public CasAuthenticationFilter casAuthenticationFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager,
   ServiceProperties serviceProperties) throws Exception {
  CasAuthenticationFilter filter = new CasAuthenticationFilter();
  filter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager);
  filter.setServiceProperties(serviceProperties);
  return filter;
 }

Comment: above code, I have bean classes and I want to get user details